# Pictures open behind the center part of full layout in Primefaces application when using PWI

Tags: javascript, jsf, layout, primefaces, picasa

I am using PWI (Picasa Webalbum Integrator) which is Jquery plugin to fetching photos. It is working partly. I can get my photos to my xhtml-page inside the panel, but when I click it, it opens pictures behind the center layout, so I can't see them except couple of millimeters between the layout parts :)

[image: You can see one of the photos between the layout parts]

Picture:
http://aijaa.com/0054410193073

[Picasa webalbum Integrator](http://code.google.com/p/pwi/)

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function () {
    var settings = {
      username: 'TedTester'

      };
    $("#container").pwi(settings);
  });

</script>

    <p:panel>   
    <div id="container"> </div>
    </p:panel>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

I have no idea how to start to fix that and I am very thankful if somebody has time time for that kind of silly thing. I am using Primefaces 3.2 and the latest version 2.0 of PWI.
Sami

Comment: It sounds like the `z-index` style on the layout panels is higher than the `z-index` for the photos being displayed from PWI.  I don't know very much about PWI, but perhaps you can inject a Javascript that can set this style higher for the photo elements?

Comment: Thanks for commenting! I took the fancybox off so I am using pure PWI at the moment. Now it opens a photo to a new window. It is better, but not solved :) Continuing...I think that Primefaces Jquery vs PWI Jquery is causing that and using scritps and css is not so simple with JSF.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake!

Two things what you have to remember when using jquery plugins with JSF.

```
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="pwi.css"  />
<h:outputScript library="js" name="jquery.pwi.js" />
```

You have to use those tags. I used only h:outputScript for both of them and it seems to be ok, but of course not, generated html wasn't ok.

Other thing was that:

```
 <h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js" target="head" />
```

I am using jquery with is in Primefaces, without it there is a conflict between jquery versions or pwi doesn't find jquery at all. At least I think so :) No everything is working fine, so I am happy!

Sami